# Using external Javascript files inside an Angular directive template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am loading dinamically in my webapp "components", which has a directive, and a template, like the following:

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('carousel', function() {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
  left: '@',
  top: '@'
  },
  templateUrl: 'carousel.html'
};
```

});

This template can have CSS dependencies, and it will work, but it won't work with Javascript. How do you think it could work?

**Template example (carousel.html)**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="example.css" media="all"> //This works
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script> //This don't work. It doesn't even request the  file to the server.
<script>
  alert('This alert is not executed');
  function alertFn(){
    alert('This alert is not executed even calling the function from other parts of the code');
  }
</script>
<p class="templateExample">This template paragraph is loaded correctly in the view</p>
```

Comment: If this is for jQuery, just put load it in the main template and list it as a dependency. Chances are other directives will use it, too, and then you'd end up including it several times.

Comment: I wish it was for jQuery, but this components can have ANY kind of dependency, so I can see 2 options when usersimport a component into the application:
- Some file that manage the dependencies, and reload the page then.
- Some "angular" way to do it.

Comment: If it is a dependecy, I'd still just include it in the main template, I think. I'm assuming it's some kind of library. If it isn't a library, but something specific to the component, then it should just be added inside the component. But that's just my 2c.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to include it in the template but it is not working. And I can't include it in the application beforehand as new "components" are uploaded in the running application app, this "component" does include the directive, the template and so on, so you can't know in advance which dependencies you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end the problem was solved using jquery as a main dependency.

Empirically I can see that when you use the Javascript files and scripts from the templates is effectively loaded.