# Adding angular directive with javascript files as package

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am writing a directive that I want other people to reuse.

The problem I encounter is that my directive has several js files it uses, and if I want others to use it, they need to add the js files explicitly.

Is there a way to make the directive include those files so that other will only have to add the directive file?

The way it works today is by adding the js files in the main head html file.

Can I use tamplateUrl to load the js files? Iv'e seen in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656983/using-external-javascript-files-inside-an-angular-directive-template) post that loading scripts creates some problems.

Concrete Example:

index.html:

```
<body data-ng-app="example">
  <test-dir></test-dir>
</body>
```

index.js:

```
(function(angular){
  var app = angular.module('example', []);
  app.directive('testDir', function(){
    return{
       restrict: 'E',
       templateUrl: 'test-me.html'
    }
  });
})(window.angular);
```

test-me.html:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
 <div> TEXT </div>
```

test.js:

```
 function testMe() {
   console.log('blah');
 }
```

This format will call the directive and I will see the div TEXT text. BUT, I can't call the function testMe and I don't see any transfer in the network for test.js which is included in the directive's template.

How can I make it work?

Comment: tamplateUrl is for loading an HTML file or a <script> of type text/ng-template. Are you sure you mean 'directive' in "my directive has several js files it uses" or 'app'?

Comment: no, directive. what do you mean by <script> of type text/ng-template? Im using the regular script tag as "text/javascript". can you direct me to an example.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script

Comment: I editted my question so you can see what Im trying to do. Hope it will help you help me. THANKS!!!

Comment: I've had a good look into this and there doesn't seem to be a way of doing what you want to do. The JavaScript in test.js doesn't get 'called' so the function testMe() is not recognised. http://plnkr.co/edit/ZgMbu0o8SEK6CKtHjfCn?p=preview Clicking on the button Test gives an error.